# Copying and pasting from Excel to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

By using VBA , how to send outlook email to agent email saved in Column "C" if the condition (greater than number 2) is true on Column "D" , so email will be sent to email saved in cell of column "C" within the same row of C for email and D for condition ?

For example :

The body of Outlook email  :

Hi !

You have pending quotation which its number

```html
Dim valueForSubject as String, xRg As Range
'CYRIL ADDED valueForSubject ABOVE

'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("D2:D1000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 2 Then
        valueForSubject = Target.Value 'CYRIL ADDED, UNSURE OF ACTUAL VALUE
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub


Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "You have pending quotation which its number" 
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = Target.Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = valueForSubject & " other words" 'CYRIL ADDED, UNSURE OF OTHER WORDS WITHIN SUBJECT
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

.

.........................................................

Comment: Use a global variable dimensioned as a string to capture the value, then you can reference said variable through your email-subroutine.

Comment: @Cyril , could you please write the code of what you have said above ? because I didn't understand it fully .

Comment: You tried the code I provided and what was the outcome?  I see you have one change to the `To:` line from what I responded, where you have noted that you would like additional conditions added... where is that?

Answer (score 0):

Response to comment, using another global variable to capture the string, then using said gvar within the email generation:

```
Dim valueForSubject as String, xRg As Range
'CYRIL ADDED valueForSubject ABOVE

'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("D2:D1000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 2 Then
        valueForSubject = Target.Value 'CYRIL ADDED, UNSURE OF ACTUAL VALUE
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub


Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "You have pending quotation which its number" 
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "Email Address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = valueForSubject & " other words" 'CYRIL ADDED, UNSURE OF OTHER WORDS WITHIN SUBJECT
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: you have copied the condition cell , but my goal is to copy and past ;for example; cell A7 based on the conditioned apply on cell D7 within the same row . However, you copied the cell of the condition which is D7 as per my example . could you please advise .

Comment: @AhmedThakaaAl-Mubarak the above is an example.  You would need to determine your condition, which would leave to `Target.Value` becoming `Cells(7,4).Value` if you wanted `D7`, or something like `Cells(Target.Row,Target.Column-1).Value` to be more dynamic.

Comment: Thanks , and I am learning from you . I think I need to explain to you more . 
since the above comment is not working with me . Could you please apply on the whole codes snap .

the condition apply on Column D and if the condition is true , the email in column C will be copied in send TO outlook

Comment: @AhmedThakaaAl-Mubarak can you update the post to also include the new code you've generated and tested based on feedback?  That would help quite a bit, and would make more sense of the additional request.

Comment: @ Cyril , my Post is edited by using your codes , so please advise